# Bit-fields "In-class initialization" results in "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-fields, in-class-initialization

```
struct bitfield {
  int i = 0;  // ok
  int j : 8 = 0;  // error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
};
```

What is the correct syntax to initialize bit-fields using C++11 "in-class initialization" feature?

Comment: I don't think its possible, at least I can not find a way to construct it with the c++ grammar summary.

Comment: They better fix this nonsense for C++14, unless there's a good reason why this should not be done.

Comment: Was this fixed in c++14?

Comment: @dshin, Here is the [link to this issue](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1341) from Ville Voutilainen's answer. But IMO, it is not fixed yet.

Comment: The assignment is ambiguous, as amongst 8 bits, deciding which must be reset needs preexisting intuitive mathematical convention..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default values to bitfield elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057973/default-values-to-bitfield-elements/51533747).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the correct syntax to initialize bit-fields using C++11 "in-class initialization" feature?

You cannot initialize bit-fields in-class. Paragraph 9.2 of the C++11 Standard specifies the grammar for class member declarators:

> [...]
>
> *member-declarator:*
>
> > *declarator virt-specifier-seq(opt) pure-specifier(opt)*
> >
> > *declarator brace-or-equal-initializer(opt)*
> >
> > *identifier(opt) attribute-specifier-seq(opt): constant-expression*

As you can see, declarators for bit-field members cannot be terminated by a *brace-or-equal-initializer*.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @Litherum: I don't know. Perhaps an oversight?

Answer (score 13):

This was raised as Core Issue 1341 to the C++ standard, but was rejected by the C++ Core Working Group in October 2015 as NAD ("not a defect") - see http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1341

Comment: There's also recent work in this area, http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0187r1.pdf has been reviewed by EWG in Issaquah, and EWG gave direction to produce a new version of that proposal.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a constructor with initializer list to give default values to your bitfields.

```
struct bitfield {
  int i;
  int j : 8;

  bitfield() : i(0), j(0) {};
};
```

You can also create read-only fields with default values.

```
struct _UserRegister1
{
  uint8_t _RES0 : 1;
  const uint8_t reserved1 : 1;
  uint8_t _HTRE : 1;
  const uint8_t reserved2 : 3;
  uint8_t _VDDS : 1;
  uint8_t _RES1 : 1;

  _UserRegister1() : reserved1(1), reserved2(7) {};
};
```

Answer (score 2):

C++11 doesn't provide any syntax for default initializing bitfields, but [C++ 20 does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

That means your example compiles fine when your C++ compiler supports C++20:

```
struct bitfield {
  int i = 0;      // ok
  int j : 8 = 0;  // ok since C++20
  int k : 8 {0};  // ditto
};
```

Note that you might need to explicitly enable C++20 support, e.g. with `-std=c++20` when using a not too recent GCC/Clang version.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (in C++11) in-class initialize bitfields.

In MSVC and gcc (with extensions), the anonymous `union` and `struct` code lets you get around this a bit.

```
struct bitfield {
  int i = 0;  // ok
  union {
    uint32_t raw = 0;
    struct {
      int j : 8;
      int x : 3;
    };
  };
};
```

where we mix a fixed size `raw` with a `union` over bitfields, then in-class initialize the `raw` element.