# Default values to bitfield elements

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-fields

In C++11 one can do

```
struct S {int i = 42;};
```

and if one forgets to initialize the member `i` it
gets default initialized to 42. I Just tried this with
bitfields as

```
struct S {int i = 42 : 5;};
```

and am getting

> error: expected ';' before ':' token

Does this feature exist for bitfield members and if so, how do I use it?

Comment: Seems like it will eventually appear in C++20  :-)  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0683r1.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bit-fields "In-class initialization" results in "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520701/bit-fields-in-class-initialization-results-in-error-lvalue-required-as-left)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, bit-fields do not allow an initializer as part of the member declaration. You can see this in the part of the grammar that describes class members (C++11 and later, [class.mem]):

> *member-declarator:*
>       *declarator virt-specifier-seqopt pure-specifier<sub>opt</sub>*
>       *declarator brace-or-equal-initializer<sub>opt</sub>*
>       *identifieropt attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> : constant-expression*

The third form is the grammar for a bit-field declaration, but only the second form lists the *brace-or-equal-initializer*.

Comment: @Vorac: Yes. Unless you want to write a proposal to allow initializers for bit-fields.

Answer (score 20):

The syntax for bit field initialization is

```cpp
 struct S {int i: 5 = 42;};
```

and is only available in c++20: `-std=c++2a` for now

Comment: In case anyone else is looking, https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx2a indicates you need clang 6.0 for this

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a constructor to initialize a bitfield like this:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo () : i {15} {}

    int i : 5;
};

Foo foo;
cout << foo.i << endl; // 15
```

You can see it [here](http://ideone.com/eSnbsj)