# How to initialize a bitfield inside structure declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, syntax, bit-fields

MSVC++ gives me a compiler error when I try to initialize a bit field inside structure declaration:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    bool a : 1 = false; // compiler error
    bool a = false : 1; // compiler error
} ;
```

What is the syntax for initializing bit fields inside structure declaration?

Comment: Sorry, finally I came up with the right keywords to find the question already asked: [Bit-fields "In-class initialization" results in "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520701/bit-fields-in-class-initialization-results-in-error-lvalue-required-as-left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit surprised but apparently Visual Studio is correct here, if we look at the grammar from section `9.2` of the draft C++11 standard it says:

```
member-declarator:
  declarator virt-specifier-seqopt pure-specifieropt
  declarator brace-or-equal-initializeropt
  identifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt: constant-expression
```

and bit-fields are not allowed to have a *brace-or-equal-initializer*. It is not clear to me why this restriction exists though. This feels like the first time I realized a in-class [initializer makes a class a non-aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27118535/1708801).

This apparently is a [defect](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1341):

> The grammar for member-declarator (9.2 [class.mem]) does not, but should, allow for a brace-or-equal-initializer on a bit-field declarator.

This issue was apparently also caught before C++11 was finalized as we can see from [Issues Found Implementing C++0x](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3307.pdf):

> 11. (Richard Smith) class.mem: bitfield members cannot have in-class initializers
>
> The grammar does not allow a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer for a bitfield member. This seems like an
>   oversight. A brace-or-equal-initializer after a constant- expression
>   appears to be unambiguous.
>
> clang behavior: clang implements the letter of the standard.
>
> suggested resolution: Change the grammar as follows:
>
> ```
> member-declarator:
>     identifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt : constant-expression brace-or-equal-initializeropt
> ```

but apparently this feel through the cracks.

Answer (score 2):

The error I get from clang is very telling:

> bitfield member cannot have an in-class initializer

So you simply can't do it, you need a constructor that initializes the members.

Comment: Thanks. MSVC++ rather complains about `;`. Actually, it's a known issue in C++11: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1341

Comment: @SergeRogatch: "known" perhaps, but apparently not garnering any interest :-(

Comment: Although clang tends to be more conformant it does have bugs too and there are cases where clang is incorrect. I have filed several clang, gcc and Visual Studio bugs based on SO questions before.